# Different formats of CASE function SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This may seem like a dumb question, but I have always done my `CASE` functions in the following format:

```
CASE
    WHEN .... THEN ....
    ELSE ....
END AS Example
```

But recently I came across one in this format:

```
Example = CASE
             WHEN ... THEN ...
             ELSE ...
          END
```

Is this just user preference or is there a reason why one would use either format?

Comment: it's just another way that you can call your column... Select [columnName] = 15 * 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you're only targeting SQL Server, either is fine. I prefer the first version, but that's just me. It is more nuanced if you are targeting multiple RDBMS. This has nothing to do with the `case` statement. You'd have the same if it was `Foo = 42` vs `42 as Foo` vs `42 as [Foo]` - and possibly a few other variants. This is actually part of the `SELECT` syntax, for naming an output column.

Comment: Thanks Marc! Makes sense. Yeah I've always done it the same way you recommend. Didn't think about the variants whereby output field is 'Named ='. I have always used the Alias. Cheers